# How to check which function has been returned in python?

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I have two methods which take different number of arguments. Here are the two functions:

```
def jumpMX(self,IAS,list):
    pass
def addMX(self,IAS):
    pass
```

I am using a function which will return one of these functions to main.I have stored this returned function in a variable named operation.
Since the number of parameters are different for both,how do I identify which function has been returned?

```
if(operation == jumpMX):
    operation(IAS,list)
elif(operation == addMX):
    operation(IAS)
```

What is the syntax for this?Thanks in advance!

Comment: The ``self`` parameter indicates these are used as methods, not as functions. Do you return ``SomeClass.jumpMX``, or ``some_instance.jumpMX``?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi .Yep you are right, they are methods inside of a class. I return only the function.  I wish to return only a single method of the class. I return some_instance.jumpMX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can identify a function through its `__name__` attribute:

```
def foo():
  pass

print(foo.__name__)

>>> foo
```

...or in your case:

```
operation.__name__ #will return either "jumpMX" or "addMX" depending on what function is stored in operation
```

Here's a demo you can modify to your needs:

```
import random #used only for demo purposes 

def jumpMX(self,IAS,list):
    pass
def addMX(self,IAS):
    pass


def FunctionThatWillReturnOneOrTheOtherOfTheTwoFunctionsAbove(): 
    # This will randomly return either jumpMX()
    # or addMX to simulate different scenarios
    funcs = [jumpMX, addMX]
    randomFunc = random.choice(funcs)
    return randomFunc

operation = FunctionThatWillReturnOneOrTheOtherOfTheTwoFunctionsAbove()
name = operation.__name__

if(name == "jumpMX"):
    operation(IAS,list)

elif(name == "addMX"):
    operation(IAS)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import those functions and test for equality like with most objects in python.

classes.py

```py
class MyClass:
    
    @staticmethod
    def jump(self, ias, _list):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    def add(self, ias):
        pass
```

main.py

```py
from classes import MyClass


myclass_instance = MyClass()
operation = get_op()  # your function that returns MyClass.jump or MyClass.add 

if operation == MyClass.jump:
    operation(myclass_instance, ias, _list)
elif operation == MyClass.add:
    operation(myclass_instance, ias)
```

However, I must emphasize that I don't know what you're trying to accomplish and this seems like a terribly contrived way of doing something like this.

Also, your python code examples are not properly formatted. See the [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which proposes a standard style-guide for python.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not able to convey it properly. I wish to return a method(say A and B) from a function(say C).I would like to verify which method has been returned(A or B) by function(C) and code accordingly. I hope I made sense now.Thanks!

Comment: That's what the code I wrote does. Try it out. Your function C is the `get_op` in my code. methods A and B are the `MyClass.jump` and `MyClass.add`